# text fields and PHP

Tags: php, html

Does anyone know if it's possible to have several text fields that place the data into different spots in the same web page. If needed I could just use two pages, it doesn't really matter. I've heard this requires a PHP script, but I'm not sure how to set this up.

Comment: Please restate your Question and explain what exactly your requirements are, it's impossible to answer this question without a lot of guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesnt require a PHP script.
Just place as many text fields as you like, anywhere you with

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little broad and vague, but I'll give it a shot. You don't need PHP per se, especially if the data is static.

There are a number of techniques you can use to include the same text in multiple pages. Such as any scripting language (like PHP), [server side includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/ssi.html) or you could even build your pages using XML and [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) (using [`<xsl:include />`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_include.asp)), which allows you to do the inclusions on the client side.

The XSLT approach may be less portable to mobile browsers, but it's a solution that doesn't depend on the capabilities of your webserver. If you want to learn PHP, there are lots of tutorials around on the internet. I'd link you some, but frankly you're better of doing a search. Here's the [tutorial on the official PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php).

You should check with your web host which technologies are supported. PHP is fairly common scripting language, on Windows hosts you might also find ASP (don't use if you're starting from scratch) and ASP.NET.